# What underlying semantic notions explain the etymology of 'fustis'?

Tags: etymology, greek

<sub>I already consulted [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fustian) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fustis).

[Source:](https://books.google.com/books?id=IrcZEZ1bOJsC&lpg=PA56&ots=7RyAl92AYn&dq=fustaneum&pg=PA56#v=onepage&q=fustaneum&f=false) p 56. *The Merriam-Webster New Book of Word Histories* (1991).</sub>

> Another word that has undergone a similar development is *fustian*. In 
>   its earliest sense
>   **[4.]** *fustian* is 'a fabric made from cotton and linen', but like 
>   *bombast* it too is now used to mean 'pretentious speech or writing'.
>   The 
>   word itself is from **[3.]** Medieval Latin *fustaneum*, whose origin is disputed. 
>   One account traces it to **[2.]** Latin *fustis* 'club, staff', as a translation of
>   **[1.]** Greek *xylinon*, literally meaning 'wooden' (from *xylon*, 'wood, club') but applied 
>   to cotton.
>   That such an origin is at least semantically possible is shown by 
>   another Medieval Latin term referring to cotton, *lana de ligno*, literally 
>   'wool of wood'. Such a conception lies at the basis of the German word for 
>   cotton to this day, *Baumwolle*, literally 'tree-wool'. Another account de- 
>   rives *fustaneum* from the Cairo suburb Fostat (Arabic *fusṭāṭ*), where fus- 
>   tian is said to have been manufactured. Even on that route we wind up 
>   back at Latin, since *fusṭāṭ*, literally 'camp', comes (via Greek transmission) 
>   from Late Latin *fossatum* 'ditch, fosse'. See also DENIM.

What underlying semantic notions connect:

5. 1 and 2 (i.e. 'wooden' + 'cotton' to 'club, staff')?
6. 2 and 4?

Comment: Why do you not accept the quoted explanation?  Incidentally, de Vaan connects *fustis* with *futare* ("to strike"), not Greek xylinon.

Comment: @Nathaniel, as I understand it, the idea is not that *fustis* is cognate with *xylinon* but that the "cotton" sense of *fustaneum* is a loan-translation of that Greek word.

Comment: @Nathaniel The problem is not my refusal to `accept the quoted explanation`; the problem is the citation's lack of explanation of the underlying semantic notions.

Answer (score 2):

I can only make educated guesses, mostly about what the quoted paragraph is intended to mean, but these might help.

5. Note that the Greek word [ξύλινων](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BE%CF%8D%CE%BB%CE%B9%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%82#Greek) primarily means "wooden". Using the word for "wood" for a club comes pretty naturally, since clubs are made of wood. Even in English, heavy (wooden) golf clubs are called "[woods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood_(golf))". In the connection from "wooden" (ξύλινων) to "club" (**fustis**), the notion of "cotton" plays no role.
6. As I understand the quoted etymology, it says that people speaking Greek were referring to cotton using the word ξύλινων, by a somewhat inscrutable connection with wood also found in modern German. The hypothesis is, when someone wanted a Latin word for a certain kind of cloth, they thought to do in Latin what had been done in Greek: use the word for "wooden" to mean "made of cotton"; and then make a noun out of it. So, the hypothesis proposes that **fustaneum** arose from *two* somewhat strange analogies: first, wood–cotton; second, "Let's do the wood–cotton analogy in Latin analogously to what they're doing in Greek."

Note that the quoted etymology is trying to explain the origin of the English word **fustian**. It's not trying to explain the origin of the Latin word **fustis**—the origin of which is not known for sure. Even the origin of the Latin word **fustaneum** isn't known for sure. The whole thing is awash in uncertainty.

Comment: The wood-cotton connection isn't so strange if you think of cotton being introduced to a culture which is only familiar with wool. "This cotton stuff, it's like wool, but from a tree/from wood! Let's call it wood-wool."

Comment: @TKR You must be a native speaker of German. :) Just kidding; that sounds very likely indeed. I hadn't thought of the plant that makes cotton for clothes as a tree, but I just did some googling and indeed it is. (I think of "cottonwood trees" only as the bane of air conditioners.) Sadly, I've never seen commercial cotton plants in person.

Comment: +1. Thank you as always for your insight and aid. Please allow me to postpone acceptance to allow time for (changes to) other responses.

Comment: Good explanation. Let me add that in Finnish we call cotton "puuvilla"; "puu" means tree or wood and "villa" means wool. It might be a translated loan from German. (@Timere, it seems other answers might not be coming.)

Comment: Isn't it ξύλινον with an omicron, not an omega? The omega would anyway shift the stress on the iota, at least in Ancient Greek, so either ξύλινον or ξυλίνων. In fact, I would expect a stress on the last syllable, i.e. ξυλινός, ξυλινή, ξυλινόν, but that may just be me :).

Comment: From what I see on [Greek Wiktionary](https://el.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BE%CF%8D%CE%BB%CE%B9%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%82), the stress is on the first syllable in Modern Greek, but the form with the omega is a genitive plural, so it's better to use a nominative singular for citation, isn't it? It seems Modern Greek has shifted the stress to the first syllables in all forms, but Ancient Greek would have had ξυλίνων.

Comment: @MickG I haven't studied Ancient Greek in any serious way, and indeed I pasted ξύλινων out of the modern Greek Wiktionary entry. Thanks for catching that! As for the genitive plural, I hazily recall having a reason for that. I'll have to dig around a bit to see why I chose it—or else abandon it and change it to the nominative singular. Also, I hazily recall deliberately choosing Modern rather than Ancient Greek for some reason. Now seeing if I can reconstruct my reasoning from last year…